# the pipe is being closed in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am running a code for loading datasets into tables with psql, and the error shows: `the pipe is being closed`. (ADMISSIONS.csv.gz is one dataset)

What should I do to get rid of this problem?

my input is:
mimic-# \set mimic_data_dir 'D:/mimic_data'
mimic-# \i D:/aa/mimic-code-master/buildmimic/postgres/postgres_load_data_7zip.sql

```
ERROR: The pipe is being closed.
psql:D:/aa/mimic-code-master/buildmimic/postgres/postgres_load_data_7zip.sql:31: 7z e -so ADMISSIONS.csv.gz: 
child process exited with exit code 2
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the full command you are using to invoke the load? I presume you are piping the `.gz` through `7z` to extract it, but not certain.

Comment: the code i used was: \i D:/aa/mimic-code-master/buildmimic/postgres/postgres_load_data_7zip.sql.  yes, I extract the.gz through 7z.